# How to get the attribute count from json on specific value

Tags: javascript

```
var  obj = [  {
        "Name": "USA"
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "UK"
        "Score": 1
    },{
        "Name": "USA"
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "UK"
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "AUS"
        "Score": 1
    },{
        "Name": "NZ"
        "Score": 3
    },{
        "Name": "NZ"
        "Score": 2
    }];
```

By this I am using this peice of code to get Number of times Score is "2".

```
var count = 0;
for(var key in Obj)
     if(Object.keys(Obj[key]).filter(function(sub){return Obj[key][sub] === "2";}).length) ++count;
```

Now My count value is 4. But it happening in only 3 country. Is there any way I can get those value.?

I mean Number of country where score is "2".

Comment: `obj.filter(x => x.Score === 2).length`?

Comment: @haim770 Did'nt work. I want 3 as output.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes But I am not asking for remove. I asking number of counts which have `2` and then removing of duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this properly.

ES6:

```js
const obj = [{"Name": "USA","Score": 2},{"Name": "UK","Score": 1},{"Name": "USA","Score": 2},{"Name": "UK","Score": 2},{"Name": "AUS","Score": 1},{"Name": "NZ","Score": 3},{"Name": "NZ","Score": 2}];

const result = obj
  .filter(o => o.Score === 2)                // Get the proper score
  .map(o => o.Name)                          // Get the resulting names
  .filter((o,i,a) => i === a.lastIndexOf(o)) // Filter for unique names
  .length;
  
console.log(result);
```

Methods used:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

---

ES5, for backwards compatibility:

```js
var obj = [{"Name": "USA","Score": 2},{"Name": "UK","Score": 1},{"Name": "USA","Score": 2},{"Name": "UK","Score": 2},{"Name": "AUS","Score": 1},{"Name": "NZ","Score": 3},{"Name": "NZ","Score": 2}];

var result = obj
  .filter(function(o){
    return o.Score === 2;
  })
  .map(function(o){
    return o.Name
  })
  .filter(function(o,i,a){
    return i === a.lastIndexOf(o);
  })
  .length;
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the matching elements and use [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

**DEMO**

```js
var myobj = [{
    "Name": "USA",
    "Score": 2
},{
    "Name": "UK",
    "Score": 1
},{
    "Name": "USA",
    "Score": 2
},{
    "Name": "UK",
    "Score": 2
},{
    "Name": "AUS",
    "Score": 1
},{
    "Name": "NZ",
    "Score": 3
},{
    "Name": "NZ",
    "Score": 2
}];

var result = myobj.filter(t => t.Score === 2);
console.log(result.length);
```

**EDIT**

```js
 var myobj = [{
        "Name": "USA",
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "UK",
        "Score": 1
    },{
        "Name": "USA",
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "UK",
        "Score": 2
    },{
        "Name": "AUS",
        "Score": 1
    },{
        "Name": "NZ",
        "Score": 3
    },{
        "Name": "NZ",
        "Score": 2
    }];

var result = _.uniq(_.map(myobj, 'Score')).length
  
 console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't remove duplicate. Same result OP is getting

Comment: This is I am getting. I want to know number of country.